# Merge metro tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

The tags [metro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metro) and [modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) are duplicate. The proper term is neither; it’s “immersive”. (Confirmed in Windows 8.1)

Comment: Seems we already did that, but the synonym must've been deleted or something. Will merge and synonymize again. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @slhck It seems they've renamed it *again*, making the earlier question obsolete.

Comment: @DanielBeck There doesn't seem to be an specific name for it anymore. They changed to "Microsoft Design Language", but that sounds more on the development side. [Wikipedia seems to think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_UI#Name_change) that they just use "Windows Store apps" and "Windows 8 apps". Perhaps we should have another vote, but I'm personally in favour of keeping either [tag:metro] or [tag:modern-ui], and leaning towards the former. Or maybe [tag:Windows-app]? Though there isn't much distinction between "app" and "program" if taken out of context.

Comment: IE11 now uses “immersive” throughout, which is pretty much the only place in Windows where they use a term for it.